# How to convert a var in an array after it is created?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Working on my first JS app, BlackJack, and have been stuck at this point for a while: what I'm trying to do is if var a is called from the array it could = 11 or 1 depending on the total value. Is there no way to change the value of an item in an array after you set up said array?

```
    var j = 10;
    var q = 10;
    var k = 10;
    var a;
    var totalPlayer = 12;
    var cards = [2, 2, ..., a, a, a];
function processIt() {
    playerCard1 = cards[48]; //this is calling for var a form the array
    if (totalPlayer > 11) {
        a = 1;
    } else {
        a = 11;
    }
    var cpu1 = document.getElementById("cpu1");
    cpu1.innerHTML = playerCard1; //this is calling for var a form the array
    }
```

I have also tried converting it to a sting then back to a var, failed.

Comment: There is, but the values in the array are not `a`; they are copies of the value of `a`.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want to achieve and why.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading correctly, you've set up your array

```
var cards = [2, 2, ..., a, a, a];
```

and now you want to change all those `a`'s?

Unfortunately (since a is a primitive) you'll have to manually change the values in your array that currently equal `a`, and set them to the updated value.

```
for (var i = 0, max = cards.length; i < max; i++)
    if(cards[i] === a)
       cards[i] = newValue;
```

**EDIT**

As hop points out, just be aware that if `a` is equal to 2, then **all** indexes in your array equal to 2 will be replaced—those first few indexes that you manually set to 2, and also those indexes at the end that you set to `a`.  But since you say that `a` will either be 1 or 11, it looks like you've set things up in such a way that this won't be an issue.

Comment: I disagree. This will replace other index with same value too !!

Comment: @hop - yes it will.  I'll update my answer to make sure the user knows that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you are expecting this way.

```
var a = 1;
var cards = [2, 2, a, a, a];
a = 5;
alert(cards); // This should print 2,2,5,5,5 is what you expect. 
              // But, it will only print 2,2,1,1,1
```

You can store all the indexes for which you set the value as 'a'. After all, you are constructing the array and it should be no hurdle for you.

In our case, you will have another array

```
var aIndexes = [2,3,4];
```

Then you can change the value of cards array like below.

```
if (totalPlayer > 11) {
    a = 1;
} else {
    a = 11;
}
for(var i =0; i< aIndexes.length; i++){
 cards[i] = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
var cards = [2, 2, ..., a, a, a];
```

...*copies* the *value* of `a` into the last three array positions. Those values have no relationship with `a` itself. Changing `a` later has *no effect* on the array. It must be updated manually:

```
if (totalPlayer > 11) {
    a = 1;
} else {
    a = 11;
}
cards.splice(-3, 3, a, a, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a;
…
var cards = [2, 2, ..., a, a, a];
```

puts the *value* of `a` *at the time of creation* of the `Array` instance as element of the array, *not* some sort of pointer to `a`.  It is equivalent here to

```
var cards = [2, 2, ..., undefined, undefined, undefined];
```

You can either modify the array directly, as others have pointed out, or store references to an `Object` instance in the array (references are values). Modifying a property of that `Object` instance would modify it for all references to the `Object` instance then.

```
var a = {
  toString: function () { return String(this.valueOf()); },
  valueOf:  function () { return this.value; }
};

// …

var cards = [2, 2, ..., a, a, a];

function processIt()
{
  var playerCard1 = cards[48];

  if (totalPlayer > 11)
  {
    a.value = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    a.value = 11;
  }

  var cpu1 = document.getElementById("cpu1");
  cpu1.innerHTML = playerCard1;
}
```

Accessing `a` in string or numeric expression context would then yield the value of the `value` property of the `Object` instance referred to by `a`:

```
/* y + a.valueOf() */
var x = y + a;

/* z + a.toString() */
var y = z + String(a);
```

You must decide whether either approach makes sense in your case, as I do not know Blackjack well, and your question is rather confused.

BTW, you have forgotten to declare `playerCard1` which causes it to leak into outer execution contexts or causes a runtime error (ES 5.x strict mode). I have fixed it for you. In general, you want to reduce the number of global variables to the absolute necessary minimum.